# What is this DIP20 microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, identification

This microcontroller failed in an electric fireplace. I'm trying to identify it, but the markings are ground off.

I've narrowed down the pins to something like the below chart, but I'm unable to locate any microcontrollers matching this description (VCC pin 5, VSS/GND pin 16, OSC/XTAL on 13/14).

```
1   GPIO o  GPIO    20
    GPIO    GPIO
    GPIO    GPIO
    GPIO    GPIO
    VCC     VSS
    GPIO    NC
    GPIO    XTAL1   14
    GPIO    XTAL2   13
    NC      GPIO
10  GPIO    GPIO    11
```

[image: top view]

Bottom view (mirrored, upside down):

[image: bottom view (mirrored, upside down)]

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. Why do you want to identify it, anyway? It's not like you could replace it; that would require the program.

Comment: Yeah. What’s the purpose of identifying it?

Comment: It's a pretty simple microcontroller (basically just responds to switches and does some PWM) so would be trivial to replace.

Comment: Might be a PLD, or an ASIC.  If you're going to go to the trouble of programming, you could make a swizzle board with your own micro surface-mounted on it, and pins to go where the original went.

Comment: I think it's a generic microprocessor because the markings were ground off, and probably not a PLD because it has a crystal attached. If it comes down to it I'll probably just socket it and replace it with a swizzle board and an AVR.

Comment: I'll be quite surprised if that thing's a crystal--looks more like a ceramic resonator. Does the same job, though.

Comment: Why do you think it has failed? It is rare for such devices to fail, are you sure the problem is not elsewhere?

Comment: @KevinWhite The chip drives transistors that enable or disable heating elements/lights/motors/etc. The chip itself is failing to engage some of these elements but I'm able to "manually" engage them by driving the circuit myself. Basically everything is working other than the chip (although I didn't check the oscillator, but the chip responds to IR so I'm assuming that works).

Comment: If you know what microcontroller it is you still have the problem of not having access to the software. If you reversed engineer the circuit well enough to know how it works the best bet is to replace it with a CPU you are comfortable with. If the pinouts don't match create a daughter card to rewire it to the board.

Comment: Nice to know they still use sandpaper like they did 45 yrs ago when I had to fix a new design from a Silicon Valley with 40 chips with print sanded off the top for a new synthesizer. But this one will have a Flashed ROM

Comment: Seems it has a standard ceramic resonator oscillator on pins 13, 14 and +power supply pin 4 with ground on pin 16. Clues for a search - good luck.

Comment: Well, if you already have the pinout, the operating voltage, the functionality required, and you are planning to write your own program for it, why do you care what micro controller is it? Just get one with the right pin out (maybe one with fully-reconfigurable pins) and get it working.

Comment: I would strongly suspect a bad power supply.. maybe a dried out electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: Power on Pin5 and GND on Pin15 is a fairly rare pinout. From brief DigiKey search for 20-DIP oackaging only "Nuvoton" has this pinout on their N79N82x processors, except that XTAL is placed differently. How old is the entire product?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about identification of a component that was [intentionally obfuscated](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines).

Comment: @Ale..chenski This fireplace is approximately 10 years old, so that probably makes the chip 10-15 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one I could find was [PIC16C717/770/771](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41120C.pdf) but old Microchip microcontrollers have the power pins in the middle, you might find other processors as well.

Pin 6 is not really a GPIO, for the above series it's an analog ground, I see a decoupling capacitor in your pictures.

Also it looks like the xtal is placed on the secondary oscillator.

Comment: This is a good observation. I had originally thought it was a GPIO but it definitely looks like a ground of some sort at a closer look.

Answer (score 1):

Look for PIC16F88 chip, it has a similar pin out configuration.

Comment: Why the downvote?